# How can I set default value of property based on theme in MAUI

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have a simple component in MAUI. Below is simplified code.

C#:

```cs
public partial class LabeledValue : ContentView 
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ValueColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(ValueColor), typeof(Color), typeof(LabeledValue), default(Color), BindingMode.OneWay);

    public Color ValueColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(ValueColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueColorProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="EpexMauiApp.Components.LabeledValue"
             x:Name="self">
        <Label Text="Dummy text" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="{Binding ValueColor, Source={x:Reference self}}"/>
</ContentView>
```

I would like to set default value of this property based on current app theme, so when I use it like

```xml
<components:LabeledValue ValueColor="{StaticResource Blue}"/>
```

It's blue but when I simply do

```xml
<components:LabeledValue />
```

Color is set based on theme.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AppThemeBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/system-theme-changes) and the provided [Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/system-theme-changes#extension-methods) for that.

First, you need to remove the binding to `TextColor`, because this will need to be set from the code-behind, and also give the `Label` a name using the `x:Name` attribute:

```xml
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="EpexMauiApp.Components.LabeledValue"
             x:Name="self">
        <Label x:Name="MyLabel" Text="Dummy text" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
</ContentView>
```

Then, in your code-behind, you need to set the `AppThemeBinding` programmatically in the constructor:

```cs
public LabeledValue()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    //set default values for AppThemeBinding
    MyLabel.SetAppThemeColor(Label.TextColorProperty, Colors.Blue, Colors.White);
}
```

Finally, you need to add a property changed handler that sets the `TextColor` when the user overrides the default setting:

```cs
public partial class LabeledValue : ContentView 
{
    public Color ValueColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(ValueColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ValueColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ValueColor), typeof(Color), typeof(LabeledValue), propertyChanged: OnValueColorPropertyChanged);

    private static void OnValueColorPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        ((LabeledValue)bindable).MyLabel.TextColor = (Color)newValue;
    }
}
```

When you use the `LabeledValue` control, you can either use the default behavior, which will respond to the App Theme or override it:

```xml
<!-- use default AppThemeBinding values -->
<components:LabeledValue/> 

<!-- permanently set the ValueColor to Orange-->
<components:LabeledValue ValueColor="Orange"/>
```

You can find a working example for this in my [MAUI Samples](https://github.com/ewerspej/maui-samples) repository.

Comment: Thet's really not an answer here. I want default value to be specified by theme, but with possibility to override it.

Comment: @JoeDoe I've updated the answer to match your described scenario.